# Unable to find Controller Name .net core 2.0

Tags: asp.net-mvc, .net-core

I have created a controller without attaching **Views** to it see if I can manually add view to the controller. This command I run first:

```
$ dotnet-aspnet-codegenerator -p . controller -name Test -outDir Controllers
```

By default, Index() action method is always there. So, I created Index.cshtml within **`View/Test`** folder to see, if I can view the controller's view by going to my app url path as:

```
localhost:5000/Test/Index
```

But, unfortunately it returns following message, in the console log:

```
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[2]
  Request finished in 0.1346ms 404
```

How to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved by my problem by inheriting a different **Controller** class in which I had defined **ApiController** attribute which is **MainController.cs** file. All my controller classes derives MainController class. At last, I put `[HttpGet("Index")]` above the action method, I know it seems unnecessary, but it worked with an instant.